# Why won't my h tags vertically align?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

In my code I used h tags for the different text i wanted to display. But for some reason, my h5 and h6 tags won't vertically align nicely to the left. It also looks like the text in the header is doing something to it

HTML

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Amanda Farrington</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>


    <div id="header">
        <a href="index.html"><div id="leftHeader">
        <img src="assets/logo2.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:65px;height:65px">
        <h1>Amanda Farrington</h1>
    </div>
        <div id="nav">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html/#workJump">Work</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="notes.html">Notes</a></li>
      </ul>
        </div>
    </div>



    <div id="hero2">
        <h6>Project Type</h6>
        <h5>Project Title</h5>
    </div>


    <div id="workImage">
        <img src="assets/trees.jpg" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;height:100%">
    </div>

    <div id="workInfo">
        <p>BOUT MY PROJECTS<p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*----------header styles-------------*/
#header {
  color: #D7DADB;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size : 15px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 3em;
  position: relative;
  height: 15%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 1em;

}


#header img
{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

h1{
width: 9em;
float: left;
padding-left: 0.5em;
color: #45CCCC;
padding-bottom: 1px;
}

#nav {
  width: 50%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-align: right;
  color: red;
  font-size:20px;
  float: right;
  padding-right: 2em;

}

#nav ul {
  padding: 1px;
}

#nav li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 38px;
}

#nav li a {
  color: #2C3E50;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav li a:hover {
  color: #45CCCC;
}

    /*----------work page styles-------------*/
#hero2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 10em;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    top: 5em;
}

#workImage
{
    top: 9%;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: static;

}

#workInfo{

    width: 70%;
    height: 50em;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

}

p{
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 25px;
      color: #2C3E50;
    float: left;
}
h5{

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 40px;
      color: #2C3E50;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

h6{

    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #45CCCC;
    float: left;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your parent containers are collapsing since you're applying `float:left;` to your `<p>`, `<h5>`, and `<h6>` tags. Floats take items out of the document flow. So when you float all elements within a `div`, the `div` will collapse because it doesn't think anything is in the `div`. To force the `div` to respect floated elements within itself, you need to apply a `clearfix` class to `#hero2`. This will push down the image and text immediately below the hero down.

**`clearfix` CSS**

```
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
```

To understand **`clearfix`** better, read [this SO thread: "Which method of `clearfix` is best?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211383/which-method-of-clearfix-is-best)